# React native custom component props not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, expo, textinput

Hey there so I am trying to use a custom text input and giving it props like autoCorrect, autoCapitalise, etc but for some reason are not working and only work when I use them directly on the original TextInput imported from react native module. Here is my code of how I am doing it. Please help me see where or what I am doing wrong.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import AppTextInput from '../components/AppTextInput';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import Screen from '../components/Screen';
import AppBtn from '../components/AppBtn';
import AppText from '../components/AppText';

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().required().email().label('Email'),
  password: Yup.string().required().min(4).label('Password'),
});

export default function LoginScreen() {
  const img = require('../assets/logo.png');

  return (
    <Screen>
      <Image source={img} style={styles.logo} />

      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}>
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, errors }) => (
          <>
            <AppTextInput
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              icon="email"
              onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
              keyboardType="email-address"
              placeholder="email"
            />
            <AppText style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.email}</AppText>
            <AppTextInput
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={true}
              icon="lock"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              placeholder="password"
            />
            <AppText style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.password}</AppText>
            <View style={styles.btn}>
              <AppBtn title="Login" onPress={handleSubmit} />
            </View>
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </Screen>
  );
}
```

and then the appTextInput itself is this

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function AppTextInput({ icon, placeholder }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* render only if icon is defined */}
      {icon && (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} size={40} style={styles.icon} />
      )}
      <TextInput style={{ fontSize: 25 }} placeholder={placeholder} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Where could I be going wrong? And even without `formik` and yup, it was still refusing even to console log out the values from the input fields. Thanks in advance for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for those props to work, you will have to supply them to the actual `TextInput` component. In your `LoginScreen` component, you are using the `AppTextInput` the correct way.

But in your `AppTextInput` component, you are only handling two props, `icon` and `placeholder`. To make the other `TextInput` props work, you will have to supply them to your `TextInput` component.

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function AppTextInput(props) {
  const { icon, placeholder } = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* render only if icon is defined */}
      {icon && (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} size={40} style={styles.icon} />
      )}
      <TextInput
        {...props}
        style={{ fontSize: 25 }}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here, I've added the passed props to the `TextInput` component with  `{...props}`. Now your props are also passed down to the `TextInput` component and it should work as expected.